# Does the OpenD6 OGL allow creating computer games?

Tags: ogl, d6-system

As OpenD6 is a bit older (2009 while the ogl used is from 2000) there was probably no thought about the recent trend of digitalization and usage of RPG rules in computer games. So I'm wondering there. If I create an RPG system using OpenD6 am I then also allowed to use that system in a computer game according to the OGL (reading through the OGL a few times which is in essence the Wizards of the Coast OGL... I'm not 100% there)?

Comment: The phrasing here makes the question slightly unclear to me, are you asking "will OGL let me make a computer game using Open D6?"

Comment: @doppelgreener In essence yes that is what I'm asking. with both possible situations a.) I'm creating a full rpg and then port it to the computer or b.) I'm doing "just" the computer game.

Comment: NB that [OpenD6 actually dates to mid-2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D6_System#The_Purgatory_Publishing_Era). The 2000 copyright year you're looking at is likely for the OGL itself. (As far as I know, the only game that shares a release year with the OGL itself is D&D 3.0.) I've left that uncorrected in the edit because it's sort of part of where the question is coming from.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Tnx. will correct that part (I mistook things there as it used the ogl from 2000 and thus I thought it by itself was from 2000^^')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will talk to the 5e OGL portion, as I don't know much about D6.  You may under OGL use SRD content in a computer game, but the files where the SRD content reside must be released under the OGL as derivative work.

While the D6 doesn't talk about software, it *should* be the same case -- those files which contain open material would be derivative and have to be open under the same license. While the license doesn't mention the method of distrobution, the license doesn't forbid software usage (which I know some between version of the OGL did).

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. When in doubt, contact a lawyer versed in copyright law.

Comment: Pretty certain this is correct - I'll add here that most of the media restrictions (preventing use in computer games and other interactive products) appear in the separate Trademark licenses (such as the d20 and Pathfinder licenses that allow you to use their logos and other elements) and as long as you *only* use the OGL, you should be protected (as long as you follow the clause about keeping reused content accessible under the OGL, typically meaning you have to make it available in a human-readable format within the program's data files)

Comment: From what I've seen in the D6 OGL page they use the full OGL formulations from wizard and "just" added their name in addition to wizards (and D6 as name) to it.